# How to configure data feed in my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, datafeed

I am creating a classified website in asp.net(C#), and i don't want to insert products manually, and i want to do this using data feed websites but i don't know how to do this using other any data-feed website like eBay. please tell me how to insert products from other data feed site to my own site.

Answer (score 0):

Tou can use best article from [Tutplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/how-to-build-an-rss-feed-with-asp-net/)

> RSS is a web content syndication format. It stands for “Really
>   Simple Syndication,” and is written in XML. All RSS files must conform
>   to the XML 1.0 specification, as published by the World Wide Web
>   Consortium (W3C). With RSS, it is possible to distribute up-to-date
>   web content from one web site to thousands of others around the world.
>   To simplify the term, RSS allows fast browsing for news and updates.